# WPF Attached Property of type ICommand

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, attached-properties

I want to implement a new Attached Property for buttons which registers if the mouse is over and executes a Command if so.
This is the C# code:

```html
public class MouseMovement 
    {

     
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseOverCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MouseOverCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MouseMovement), 
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(MouseOverCommandChanged)));




       

        private static void MouseOverCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)d;
            element.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(element_MouseOver);
        }

        private static void element_MouseOver(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
            ICommand cmd = GetMouseOverCommand(element);
            cmd.Execute(e);
        }

        public static void SetMouseOverCommand(UIElement element, ICommand value)
        {
            element.SetValue(MouseOverCommandProperty, value);
        }

        private static ICommand GetMouseOverCommand(FrameworkElement element)
        {
            return (ICommand)element.GetValue(MouseOverCommandProperty);
        }
}
```

And the xaml:

```html
<Button mouseEvents:MouseMovement.MouseOverCommand="{Binding ButtonMouseOverCommand}"  Grid.Row="0" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" >
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image />
                    <TextBlock Text="BL-Invoices" Foreground="White"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
```

Everytime I try to run this I get the error: "Binding can not be specified for the property "SetMouseOverCommand" of type button. Binding can only be specified for a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject"

I got a little bit stuck at this point, maybe you have some ideas.

Edit: As stated in the accepted answer the mistake was a typo. The AttachedProperty name was set to "MouveOverCommand" instead of "MouseOverCommand". I edited the code snippet to be correct.

Comment: make GetMouseOverCommand `public`

Comment: Agree should be public, but still not the final solution. The excetpion´s still there. The element in 'GetMouseOverCommand' should probably be a UIElement too, but that still doesn´t make the difference.

Comment: You should use behaviors instead (Windows.Interactivity).

Comment: @DerrickMoeller Sometimes it is better to read over the stuff you write again. However, thank you!

Comment: @Leandro thanks I will take a look.

Comment: So was it the typo noticed by @DerrickMoeller? If the typo was just in the question, please [edit] the question to reflect your real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's just a typo, I put your code into a sample project and it worked as expected.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseOverCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MouseOverCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MouseMovement), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(MouseOverCommandChanged)));
```